# Creating a count variable for number of years since a base observation

Tags: r, date, dataframe, datediff, panel-data

I need to create a variable that tells me the number of years since the first observation of a specific group, *conflictID*. I have provided a sample dataset to illustrate my problem.

```
conflictID <- c(205,205,205,209,209,221,221,221,221)
year <- c("1993", "1995", "1996", "1991", "1993", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2005")
df <- data.frame(conflictID, year)
```

The output of this data frame is:

```
      conflictID year
1        205     1993
2        205     1995
3        205     1996
4        209     1991
5        209     1993
6        221     2001
7        221     2002
8        221     2003
9        221     2005
```

I would like something that looks like this:

```
      conflictID year   duration
1        205     1993       0
2        205     1995       2
3        205     1996       3
4        209     1991       0
5        209     1993       2
6        221     2001       0
7        221     2002       1
8        221     2003       2
9        221     2005       4
```

where the *duration* variable is 0 for the first observation of each *conflictid*. Basically, what I need is a way of setting the benchmark date for the first year of each *conflictID* if that makes sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use the `dplyr` library. `df2` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(year = as.numeric(as.character(year))) %>%
  group_by(conflictID) %>%
  mutate(duration = year - min(year))

df2
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   conflictID [3]
  conflictID  year duration
       <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1        205  1993        0
2        205  1995        2
3        205  1996        3
4        209  1991        0
5        209  1993        2
6        221  2001        0
7        221  2002        1
8        221  2003        2
9        221  2005        4
```

Notice that your `year` column is in `factor` format, which is difficult to work on. I would suggest you maintain the year column in `numeric` format when you create your data frame. Please see the following example. If you remove quotation mark in the year column. You don't need `mutate(year = as.numeric(as.character(year)))` for your code.

```
conflictID <- c(205,205,205,209,209,221,221,221,221)
year <- c(1993, 1995, 1996, 1991, 1993, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2005)
df <- data.frame(conflictID, year)
```

Comment: I have tried it both on the sample dataset and my original dataset but neither seem to have worked. There are no error messages, but the values in the *duration* column are wrong. I recreated my data frame with year as numeric, and then used your code and this is the result:

    conflictID  year duration
       <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1        205  1993        2
2        205  1995        4
3        205  1996        5
4        209  1991        0
5        209  1993        2
6        221  2001       10
7        221  2002       11
8        221  2003       12
9        221  2005       14

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise you couldn't put code into answers, should I reproduce my code in a separate answer to my own question? I am new to stackoverflow so don't really know the protocols!

Comment: Did you `group_by(conflictID)`?

Comment: Update: I rewrote the code putting dplyr:: before the mutate and group_by functions and that did the trick!

Answer (score 3):

One line in base R...

```
df$year <- as.numeric(as.character(df$year)) #your years are factors

df$duration <- df$year - ave(df$year, df$conflictID, FUN=min)

df
  conflictID year duration
1        205 1993        0
2        205 1995        2
3        205 1996        3
4        209 1991        0
5        209 1993        2
6        221 2001        0
7        221 2002        1
8        221 2003        2
9        221 2005        4
```

Answer (score 3):

Another one-liner in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, duration := year - min(year), conflictID]
df
#   conflictID year duration
#1:        205 1993        0
#2:        205 1995        2
#3:        205 1996        3
#4:        209 1991        0
#5:        209 1993        2
#6:        221 2001        0
#7:        221 2002        1
#8:        221 2003        2
#9:        221 2005        4
```